# Missing hermit crab

Tags: molting, hermit-crabs

My daughter purchased two hermit crabs a week ago. I got up this morning to discover the biggest green shelled crab was missing. I took everything out of the tank (it is a small starter tank) and can’t find him. We have two sponges in the tank and one sponge is noticeably heavier today-but I can’t see any green inside the sponge. We can’t find the green shell anywhere or the crab for that matter. I considered that maybe he climbed out but there is no way he could have gotten traction on the side of the tank walls and there is nothing vertical for him to have scaled up on.  We are stumped as to what happened…if any hermie owners have experience with this please let me know!

Comment: How is your tank shaped? Hermit crabs only go into the water short times and then go back to "islands".

Comment: What size are the crabs? How tight is the lid on the aquarium? Is there any space around it that it could have escaped? A long time ago I had some kind of crabs in my aquarium, small size, less than half inch diameter. They escaped and died quickly. I found one of them about 6..10 m away from the aquarium. I was more than impressed. So, did you search around the room, and under the furniture / equipment / whatever you have in that room, and in the rooms nearby?